# R Create table using mean of multiple columns from other table

Tags: r

I have a table:

```
> head(TiposMotivA)
  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 Q8 Q9 Q10 Q11 Q12 Q13 Q14 Q15 Q16 Q17 Q18 Q19 Q20 Q21
1  5  4  4  4  6  6  7  6  4   6   6   6   4   4   4   4   6   7   4   4   6
2  5  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5   5   7   5   4   3   1   6   6   5   6   7   7
3  4  5  4  4  5  4  5  4  5   4   5   4   5   4   5   4   5   4   5   4   5
4  5  5  7  7  4  6  6  6  7   7   6   7   7   6   6   7   4   7   6   6   7
5  6  1  7  6  7  7  7  7  7   7   6   7   2   2   3   6   3   7   7   7   7
6  4  4  3  3  4  5  4  3  4   7   6   6   4   4   6   4   5   7   6   6   7
```

Here is its put:

```
> dput(head(TiposMotivA))
structure(list(Q1 = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L), Q2 = c(4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 4L), Q3 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 3L), Q4 = c(4L, 5L, 
4L, 7L, 6L, 3L), Q5 = c(6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 4L), Q6 = c(6L, 5L, 
4L, 6L, 7L, 5L), Q7 = c(7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4L), Q8 = c(6L, 5L, 
4L, 6L, 7L, 3L), Q9 = c(4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L), Q10 = c(6L, 
5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L), Q11 = c(6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Q12 = c(6L, 
5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 6L), Q13 = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 4L), Q14 = c(4L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L), Q15 = c(4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L), Q16 = c(4L, 
6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 4L), Q17 = c(6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L), Q18 = c(7L, 
5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L), Q19 = c(4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L), Q20 = c(4L, 
7L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 6L), Q21 = c(6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L)), .Names = c("Q1", 
"Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", 
"Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q19", "Q20", 
"Q21"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I need new is to create another table by using this table columns. It must have the follow structure:
Column A values come from mean of columns Q1 and Q11
Column B values come from mean of columns Q10 and Q21

The final result is expected to be:

```
     A    B
1  5.5    6
2    6    6
3  4.5  4.5
4  5.5    7
5    6    7
6    5    7
```

To help you understand, the calculation is:

```
1A = (6 + 5) / 2
1B = (6 + 6) / 2
And so on...
```

Is there a fuction I can use to do this?

I thought this one would do the trick, but I was mistaken...

```
> c(mean(c(TiposMotivA$Q1,TiposMotivA$Q11)),mean(c(TiposMotivA$Q11,TiposMotivA$Q21)))
[1] 5.645161 6.395161
```

But instead of calculating mean for each row it took mean from all values in each row and then calculated the mean.
Then I tried this:

```
Teste$A <- tapply(TiposMotivA$Q1,TiposMotivA$Q11,mean)
Teste$B <- tapply(TiposMotivA$Q10,TiposMotivA$Q21,mean)
```

No success again... I know I must be far from what I need, so I ask for help...
Any clues are gonna be very appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)                  #load library
new_df <- df %>%
          #use mutate to create the mean columns                   
          mutate(A=(Q1+Q11)/2, B=(Q10+Q21)/2 ) %>% 
          select(A,B)             #only select A and B which you need
```

Or

```
new_df <- transmute(df, A=(Q1+Q11)/2, B=(Q10+Q21)/2)
```

**Output**

```
new_df
    A   B
1 5.5 6.0
2 6.0 6.0
3 4.5 4.5
4 5.5 7.0
5 6.0 7.0
6 5.0 7.0
```

Comment: Happy to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it without using any external library, but a little bit more combersome and hard to read.

```
data.frame(A=(TiposMotivA$Q1+TiposMotivA$Q11)/2, B=(TiposMotivA$Q10+TiposMotivA$Q21)/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
#if the columns are to be created in the same dataset 
setDT(TiposMotiva)[,c('A', 'B'):= list((Q1+Q11)/2, (Q10+Q21)/2)]
#if you need another dataset with the newly created columns
DTNew <- setDT(TiposMotiva)[, list(A=(Q1+Q11)/2, B=(Q10+Q21)/2)]
```

Or using `rowMeans` in `base R`.  This would be useful if there are `NAs`

```
 as.data.frame(sapply(list(TiposMotiva[c('Q1', 'Q11')], 
               TiposMotiva[c('Q10', 'Q21')]), rowMeans, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Or if this needs to be done for many columns (i.e. getting the mean value for each row from corresponding `n` columns), we could use `Reduce` after placing the subset dataset in a list.  Here, the "means" will be between columns `1 and 11`, `2 and 12`, `3 and 13` etc. (NOTE: In the given dataset, the pattern is not specific (i.e. `Q1 and Q11`, `Q10 and Q21`))

```
n <- 2
Reduce(`+`, list(TiposMotiva[1:10], TiposMotiva[11:20]))/n
```

Or

```
f1 <- function(x,y) colMeans(rbind(x,y), na.rm=TRUE)
df1 <- setNames(TiposMotiva[1:10], LETTERS[1:10])
df1[] <- Map(f1,  TiposMotiva[1:10], TiposMotiva[11:20])
```